# Angular Material <mat-toolbar> hides when refresh page

Tags: angular

I'm developing an Angular Material app.

I have this mat-toolbar in **my app.component.html**:

```
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async" fullscreen>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
        <h1>SAP</h1>
    </mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches">
    <mat-nav-list>
        
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/trafos">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="fohama"></mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Transformadores</span>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/empleados">
                <mat-icon>assignment_ind</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Empleados</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/clientes">
                <mat-icon>assignment_ind</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Clientes</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/procesos">
                <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Procesos</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/modificarProcesos">
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Modificar Procesos</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/order">
                <mat-icon>low_priority</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Priorizar Transformadores</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/referencias">
                <mat-icon>add_comment</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Referencias</span>   
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item *ngIf="isOp==false" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/reportes">
                <mat-icon>insert_chart_outlined</mat-icon> <span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  Reportes</span>   
            </a>

            <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" (click)="logout()">
                <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon><span class="nav-caption">&nbsp;  logout</span>
            </a>

        
    </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

everything works fine. This bar is in the app component and, ngOnInit() y have this:

```
  this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
}
```

The problem that i have is when the user reloads the page. The navBar dissapears.
What would be the best solution to fix it?
When the user logs, the system saves a token in localStorage. I thought to use it, but i don´t know how to determine the condition in the ngIf because i have the async pipe in it.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
This is my auth.Service:

```
export class AuthService {
  apiUrl = `${environment.baseUrl}/auth`;
  message:string;
  durationInSeconds:1;
  isOp:boolean=true;
  sector:number=0;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  userChange$ = new BehaviorSubject({isOp: null, sector: null});
  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); 
  }
  

  constructor(private http:HttpClient,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,private router:Router) { }

  login(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/login`, data)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => 
          {
            //console.log(_);
            this.openSnackBar("Sesión iniciada");
            this.loggedIn.next(true);
            this.userChange(_.isOp,_.sector);
            this.isOp=_.isOp;
            this.sector=_.sector;
            //localStorage.setItem("sector",_.sector);
            //localStorage.setItem("isOp",_.isOp);
          }
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError('login Failed', ))
      );
  }

  userChange(isOp, sector){
    this.userChange$.next({
        isOp: isOp,
        sector: sector
    });
   }

   isLogged(){
     if(localStorage.getItem('sector'))
     {
       this.loggedIn.next(true);
      
     }
     
   }
  logout(){
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    localStorage.clear();
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
  }
}
```

This is my app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'client';
  isOp:boolean;
  sector:number;
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
  // isLogged$:Observable<boolean>;
//usDetail:Observable<Object>;

mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher,private router: Router,private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,sanitizer: DomSanitizer,private authService:AuthService,private mensajesService:MensajesService) {
  this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
  this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'fohama',
    sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/logofohamaico.svg')
  );
}



ngOnInit() {
  // this.isLogged=localStorage.getItem('token');
  //console.log(this.isLogged);
  // this.isLogged$ = this.tokenInterceptor.isLogged;
  this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
  console.log("")
  this.mensajesService.getMessage().subscribe(res=>{
    console.log("Respuesta: ",res);
    this.isOp=res.isOp;
  })
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
}



logout() {
  this.authService.logout();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
this is my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent,data:{title:'Login'}},
  {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent,data:{title:'Registro'}},
  {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'reportes',component:DailyReportComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path: 'empleados', component:EmpleadosComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path: 'clientes',component:ClientesComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard] },
  {path:'procesos',component:TimerReloadedComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path:'modificarProcesos',component:ModificarProcesosComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path:'order',component:OrderComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path:'referencias',component:ReferenciasComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]},
  {path:'trafos',component:TransformadoresReloadedComponent,canActivate:[GuardianGuard]}
  //{path:'**',redirectTo:'/login'}
];
```

Login Component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  nombreUs = '';
  pass = '';
  matcher = new ErrorStateMatcher();
  isLoadingResults = false;  
  messageSnack:string;
  durationInSeconds=3;
  private us = new BehaviorSubject<Object>("");
  get usDetail() {
    return this.us.asObservable(); 
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, private mensajeService:MensajesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'nombreUs' : [null, Validators.required],
      'pass' : [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.authService.login(form)
      .subscribe(res => {
        //console.log(res);
        if(res){
          this.mensajeService.enviarMensaje({
            isOp:res.isOp,
            sector:res.sector
          })
          this.us.next({isOp:res.isOp,sector:res.sector});
          if (res.token) {
             localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
          }
          if(res.isOp==true)
          {
            this.router.navigate(['procesos']);
          }
          else{
            this.router.navigate(['trafos']);
          }
        }
        else{
          this.openSnackBar("Usuario o contraseña inválidos");
        }
      }, (err) => {
        
        // this.openSnackBar("Usuario o contraseña inválidos");
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  openSnackBar(mensaje) {
    this._snackBar.open(mensaje,"mensaje", {
       duration: this.durationInSeconds * 1000,
      });
  }

  login(){

    this.router.navigate(['transformadores'])
  }

  register() {
    this.router.navigate(['register']);
  }

}

//Managing form validation

    export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
      isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
      }

}
```

So, because this toolbar is in the app.component, and the "Home Page" is the Login Component (Who calls to auth.Service), everything works fine till the user reloads the page

Comment: Does this.authService.isLoggedIn returns an observable of true?

Comment: why do you need async for local storage variable

Comment: @Udi Mazor yes, It does.

Comment: @The async is for the isLoggedIn$ variable, not for a local Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the state of a user, you should use the local storage. Because every time a user reload a page, everything is rebuild from scratch.

In your component

```
this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
```

In your auth service

```
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {

  isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private localStorage: StorageService) {
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(this.checkSessionStorage());
  }

  public login(...) {
    // make the request
    this.storageService.setToken(a_Token);
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
  }

  public logout() {
    this.storageService.clearToken();
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(false);
  }

  public checkSessionStorage(): boolean {
    return this.localStorage.getToken() !== null;
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): Obseravable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoggedIn$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In your storage service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';

const TOKEN = 'token';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StorageService {

  constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

  getToken(): string {
    return this.localStorageService.retrieve(TOKEN);
  }

  setToken(token: string): void {
    this.localStorageService.store(TOKEN, token);
  }

  clearToken() {
    this.localStorageService.clear(TOKEN);
  }
}
```

When the user login and logout, you need respectively set and clear the token.

Of course, it is just a basic use case. You do not have to call the storage every time and you might want to made it as an observable. The first time the user load the app, it will call the storage, keep it in memory and reuse it while the user has not refresh the app.

I hope it can be useful :)

Comment: thank for your answer...my problem with your solution is that the app inits with the loginComponent, and the appComponent doesn´t have a token in localStorage yet...

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, the `isAuthenticated()` just check whether or not a token is present. Or maybe I didn't understand well.
Usually, what I do, is add a Guard `CanActivate` and for example, you check if the token is present. If you have a token you can continue, if you don't have a token, it means the user is not authenticated and you redirect to the login page instead.

Comment: yes, but when the appComponent starts with the LoginComponent, the appComponent has a false with isAuthenticated()... Then, when a users log in, the LoginComponent redirects the user to another page with router.navigate(), and the appComponent still having the false of the isAuthenticated() method...

Comment: When you login, you set the token so it should be true ? Or maybe I am missing something

Comment: Yes, the loginComponent sets the token, but i dont know why the app.component doesnt update that change, that Is the reason because i tried with an observable. If i reload the page, the appComponent change

Comment: Could you provide your login component please ?

Comment: Oh maybe I see. Your app.component is just where you put the `router-outlet` ? 
So indeed the app component is init one time, you need an observable. 
After logging in, if you reload the page, does it update the app.component correctly with the token ?

Comment: Yes, it does... if you reload, the app.component updates

Comment: I think, you need the storage to retrieve the session when the user reload and during the navigation, you keep an observable up to date for your `app.component`. I updated my answer. It's more like a pseudo code, but the idea is here ^^

Comment: Awesome !  
No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this.authService.isLoggedIn returns an observable of true?

I suspect not. Try configuring isLoggedIn$ as behaviourSubject and on ngOnInit call this.authService.isLoggedIn.next(this.authService.isLoggedIn)

```
isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

ngOninit() {
this.isLoggedIn$.next(this.authService.isLoggedIn);
}
```

Another solution is not to use | async and in the HTML file use:

```
*ngIf=authService.isLoggedIn
```

Comment: sorry for the late...yes it does... 
i updated the post.... the problem is when i reload the page

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the async pipe subscribes after you set the observable. Try using behaviorSubject for isLoggedIn$ (that on subscribe returns the last value emitted).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have pasted really less code... I can only give some suggestions I can think of so far:

- Like others mentioned, you should check if

  ```
   this.authService.isLoggedIn
  ```

  always returns an oberservable.
- Regarding how to determine the condition in the ngIf:

  ```
  *ngIf="isLoggedIn$| async as isLoggedIn"
  ```

  You can print out the value of isLoggedIn

Comment: Sorry about the less code. I updated the post with the components